Can I delete some digits with a rewrite rule?
I have a lot of url's like this:
https://shop.com/sub/item-name-123456/
Now I have all of my items like this:
https://shop.com/sub/item-name/
Is it possible with a rewrite rule to get a 301 redirect so "-123456" is deleted from the url?
There are always 6 (different) digits at the end of the url.
Kind regards,
Arie

Yes, of course that is possible. Have you tried anything yet?

no, unfortually not. Rewriterules are for me 'abacadabra', i can read them but can't develop one :-(. What I have done so far is:
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{6})$
But I haven't got a clue if this a the right approach ...... I must somewhere do something with the 301 and make the 6 digits and the - disappear in the 301

You need to match & capture the part before the digits, so that you can use that in your substitution URL. RewriteRule (.+)-[0-9]{6}/$ $1/ [R=302,L] (302 for testing, change to 301 when you confirmed it is working as desired.)

I have try your solution, ik looks like a part of it is working, the 6 digits and the - disappear but I got redirect to a wrong url.
I did a test for https://example.com/fanshop/ajax/nike-air-ajax-trainingsshort-2024-2025-kids-black-913877/ but got redirected to https://example.com/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/fanshop/ajax/nike-air-ajax-trainingsshort-2024-2025-kids-black/
Any idea why there is suddenly the root of the webserver (var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/ in the url in stead of just example.com?

Anyone any idea why I get the webserver root in the redirected rule? In stead of https://example.com/fanshop/ajax/nike-air-ajax-trainingsshort-2024-2025-kids-black-913877/ I get redirected to https://example.com/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/fanshop/ajax/nike-air-ajax-trainingsshort-2024-2025-kids-black/

I got the solution, I forgot to type the RewriteBase on top off the htaccess, so with RewriteBase / I got it finally working!
